# How to filter the output of get-service so it won't show stopped services

Tags: powershell

I'm very sure this is something easy but since I am new in powershell I couldn't figure out a way to do it. The following command:

`Get-Service | Sort-Object -Property status -Descending`

displays services on the PC, sorts them by status so it shows running processes in the beginning of the list. Stopped services come right after started services Can I do any filter so it won't show stopped services?

*Please get in the habit of not using abbreviations when posting codes on online forum for this post and all other posts.*

Thank You!

Comment: A simple `help Get-Service -Examples` would have shown you an example which does exactly what you want (Example nr. 5).

Comment: Thanks! Like I mentioned above, I'm very new in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the PowerShell version ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion) 
You can run two commands:

PS Version 2.0 `get-service | where {$_.status -eq 'running'}`

PS Version 3.0 or greater `get-service | where status -eq 'running'`

PS Version 3.0 or greater `get-service | ? status -eq 'running'`

The big differance between the two versions are the `{Curly brackets}` and you can also use Alias `Get-Alias`

The following function will allow you to select only one service that you want to stop. After time of your choice currently 5 minutes. The service will start again. The GUI option does allow you to start and stop when you choose.

## Stop a Service

```
Function ManageService{
$Service=Get-Service | where {$_.status -eq 'running'} | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
$GUI = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
if ($Service.Status -eq "Running"){
$ServiceName=$Service.DisplayName
$Yes_Cancle = $GUI.popup("Do you want to turn stop $ServiceName ?", `
0,"Manage Service",3)
If ($Yes_Cancle -eq 6) {
Stop-Service $ServiceName 
$GUI.popup("$ServiceName service has been STOPPED and will START again in 5 minutes, soon as you hit OK")
start-Sleep -s 300
$GUI.popup("Time is up! $ServiceName service will now start as soon as you hit OK")
Start-Service $ServiceName
cls
}
else {
$GUI.popup("You decided to cancel. $ServiceName will not be stopped")
cls
}}}
cls
ManageService
```

## Kill a Process

```
Function ManageProcess{
$Process=Get-Process | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
$GUI = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
if ($Process.processname -ne "$False"){
$ProcessName=$Process.processname
$Yes_Cancle = $GUI.popup("Do you want to turn kill $ProcessName ?", `
0,"Manage Process",3)
If ($Yes_Cancle -eq 6) {
Stop-Process -processname $ProcessName
$GUI.popup("$ProcessName has been killed as soon as you hit OK")
cls
}
else {
$GUI.popup("You decided to cancel. $ProcessName will not be killed")
cls
}}}
cls
ManageProcess
```

Comment: can you do this script for get-process?

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-Service | 
 Where-Object { $Psitem.Status -ne 'Stopped' } | 
 Sort-Object -Property status -Descending
```

This effectively filters by status.

Comment: This part of the code doesn't do anything. `Sort-Object -Property status -Descending`. You are literally sorting by the Status `Running` which is all of them. If you eliminate that section of the code PowerShell will order it for you.

Comment: What makes you think that service status enumeration contains only `Stopped` and `Running` values?

Comment: That is a valid point. It could be Running, StopPending, or StartPending. The issue with pending is services is that you usually have to stop/kill the process. Which is maybe why the OP wanted the Get-Process option as well.